# AndroidViewClient: content is not allowed in trailing section

Tags: android, testing, automation, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I installed AndroidViewClient via Git on my Windows Vista machine at home and I setup the path variables and ran the check-imports.py script to make sure everything was ok.  Next, I tried to run the settings.py script from the /examples folder and got the following error:

```
C:\Users\Allen>monkeyrunner C:\Users\Allen\AndroidViewClient\AndroidViewClient\e
xamples\settings.py
130615 22:24:56.666:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
] Script terminated due to an exception
130615 22:24:56.666:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Allen\AndroidViewClient\AndroidViewClient\examples\settings.py"
, line 49, in <module>
    vc = ViewClient(device, serialno)
  File "C:\Users\Allen\AndroidViewClient\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\andr
oid\viewclient.py", line 1188, in __init__
    self.dump()
  File "C:\Users\Allen\AndroidViewClient\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\andr
oid\viewclient.py", line 1766, in dump
    self.setViewsFromUiAutomatorDump(received)
  File "C:\Users\Allen\AndroidViewClient\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\andr
oid\viewclient.py", line 1530, in setViewsFromUiAutomatorDump
    self.__parseTreeFromUiAutomatorDump(received)
  File "C:\Users\Allen\AndroidViewClient\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\andr
oid\viewclient.py", line 1688, in _ViewClient__parseTreeFromUiAutomatorDump
    self.root = parser.Parse(receivedXml)
  File "C:\Users\Allen\AndroidViewClient\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\andr
oid\viewclient.py", line 988, in Parse
    parserStatus = parser.Parse(uiautomatorxml, 1)
  File "C:\Users\Allen\android-sdks\tools\lib\jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar\Lib\xm
l\parsers\expat.py", line 212, in Parse
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: Content is not allowed in trailing section.
```

I can't seem to figure out what the error is.  I tried deleting the AndroidViewClient folder and re-downloading everything, but I still get the same error.  Any ideas what the issue could be?

EDIT: this is the output after turning the DEBUG and DEBUG_RECEIVED FLAGS on in viewclient.py

```
checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="true" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1022,712][2258,840]"><node index="0" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1038,712][1150,840]" /><node index="1" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1150,720][2110,831]"><node index="0" text="asgqa2" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1150,732][1269,781]" /><node index="1" text="Secured with WPA" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1150,781][1379,819]" /></node><node index="2" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[2110,712][2238,840]"><node index="0" text="" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[2142,744][2206,808]" /></node></node><node index="4" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="true" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1022,842][2258,970]"><node index="0" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1038,842][1150,970]" /><node index="1" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1150,850][2110,961]"><node index="0" text="CEAudit" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1150,862][1276,911]" /><node index="1" text="Secured with WPA2 (WPS available)" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1150,911][1598,949]" /></node><node index="2" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[2110,842][2238,970]"><node index="0" text="" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[2142,874][2206,938]" /></node></node><node index="5" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="true" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1022,972][2258,1100]"><node index="0" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1038,972][1150,1100]" /><node index="1" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1150,980][2110,1091]"><node index="0" text="asgqa3" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1150,992][1269,1041]" /><node index="1" text="Secured with WPA" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1150,1041][1379,1079]" /></node><node index="2" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[2110,972][2238,1100]"><node index="0" text="" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[2142,1004][2206,1068]" /></node></node><node index="6" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="true" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1022,1102][2258,1230]"><node index="0" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1038,1102][1150,1230]" /><node index="1" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1150,1110][2110,1221]"><node index="0" text="asgqa" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1150,1122][1249,1171]" /><node index="1" text="Secured with WPA" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1150,1171][1379,1209]" /></node><node index="2" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[2110,1102][2238,1230]"><node index="0" text="" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[2142,1134][2206,1198]" /></node></node><node index="7" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="true" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1022,1232][2258,1360]"><node index="0" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1038,1232][1150,1360]" /><node index="1" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1150,1240][2110,1351]"><node index="0" text="hs-dlink" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1150,1252][1281,1301]" /><node index="1" text="Secured with WPA/WPA2 (WPS available)" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1150,1301][1669,1339]" /></node><node index="2" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[2110,1232][2238,1360]"><node index="0" text="" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[2142,1264][2206,1328]" /></node></node><node index="8" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="true" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1022,1362][2258,1490]"><node index="0" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1038,1362][1150,1490]" /><node index="1" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1150,1370][2110,1481]"><node index="0" text="ASUS" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1150,1382][1241,1431]" /><node index="1" text="Secured with WPA2 (WPS available)" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1150,1431][1598,1469]" /></node><node index="2" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[2110,1362][2238,1490]"><node index="0" text="" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[2142,1394][2206,1458]" /></node></node></node></node></node></node></node></node></node></node></node></hierarchy>Killed 


130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] Script terminated due to an exception
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/allen/projects/AndroidViewClient/AndroidViewClient/examples/settings.py", line 49, in <module>
    vc = ViewClient(device, serialno)
  File "/home/allen/projects/AndroidViewClient/AndroidViewClient/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py", line 1153, in __init__
    self.dump()
  File "/home/allen/projects/AndroidViewClient/AndroidViewClient/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py", line 1731, in dump
    self.setViewsFromUiAutomatorDump(received)
  File "/home/allen/projects/AndroidViewClient/AndroidViewClient/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py", line 1495, in setViewsFromUiAutomatorDump
    self.__parseTreeFromUiAutomatorDump(received)
  File "/home/allen/projects/AndroidViewClient/AndroidViewClient/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py", line 1653, in _ViewClient__parseTreeFromUiAutomatorDump
    self.root = parser.Parse(receivedXml)
  File "/home/allen/projects/AndroidViewClient/AndroidViewClient/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py", line 953, in Parse
    parserStatus = parser.Parse(uiautomatorxml, 1)
  File "/home/allen/android/android-sdks/tools/lib/jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar/Lib/xml/parsers/expat.py", line 212, in Parse
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: Content is not allowed in trailing section.

130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyException.fillInStackTrace(PyException.java:70)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:181)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:29)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at java.lang.RuntimeException.<init>(RuntimeException.java:32)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyException.<init>(PyException.java:46)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyException.doRaise(PyException.java:219)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.Py.makeException(Py.java:1239)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.Py.makeException(Py.java:1243)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.Py.makeException(Py.java:1247)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at xml.parsers.expat$py.Parse$14(/home/allen/android/android-sdks/tools/lib/jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar/Lib/xml/parsers/expat.py:213)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at xml.parsers.expat$py.call_function(/home/allen/android/android-sdks/tools/lib/jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar/Lib/xml/parsers/expat.py)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:166)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:338)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:139)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py.Parse$54(/home/allen/projects/AndroidViewClient/AndroidViewClient/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py:954)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py.call_function(/home/allen/projects/AndroidViewClient/AndroidViewClient/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:149)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:327)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:124)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py._ViewClient__parseTreeFromUiAutomatorDump$81(/home/allen/projects/AndroidViewClient/AndroidViewClient/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py:1654)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py.call_function(/home/allen/projects/AndroidViewClient/AndroidViewClient/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:149)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:327)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:124)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py.setViewsFromUiAutomatorDump$78(/home/allen/projects/AndroidViewClient/AndroidViewClient/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py:1497)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py.call_function(/home/allen/projects/AndroidViewClient/AndroidViewClient/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:149)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:327)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:124)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py.dump$84(/home/allen/projects/AndroidViewClient/AndroidViewClient/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py:1794)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py.call_function(/home/allen/projects/AndroidViewClient/AndroidViewClient/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:301)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:127)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:317)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:109)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py.__init__$62(/home/allen/projects/AndroidViewClient/AndroidViewClient/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py:1153)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py.call_function(/home/allen/projects/AndroidViewClient/AndroidViewClient/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:301)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:194)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:387)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:381)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyInstance.__init__(PyInstance.java:120)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyClass.__call__(PyClass.java:194)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:404)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:408)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(/home/allen/projects/AndroidViewClient/AndroidViewClient/examples/settings.py:66)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(/home/allen/projects/AndroidViewClient/AndroidViewClient/examples/settings.py)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1275)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.core.__builtin__.execfile_flags(__builtin__.java:522)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:225)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at com.android.monkeyrunner.ScriptRunner.run(ScriptRunner.java:116)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.run(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:77)
130617 10:20:00.138:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:189)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm I reset my device to factory settings and suddenly it works ok :o

EDIT:
I figured out what the issue was.  I'm trying to automate the CTS testing and when the Delegating Accessibility Testing Service is enabled, it somehow causes AndroidViewClient to fail after that point in the script and on monkeyrunner executions for other scripts.  Turning it off allows any script using AndroidViewClient to behave normally again...

Comment: Interesting information. It would be useful to know exactly what's causing the error. You can enable DEBUG and DEBUG_RECEIVED in `viewclient.py` and see.

Comment: let me get back to you on this tomorrow.  I've seen the same result on a Nexus 7 and Nexus 10 device.

Comment: updated the answer.  you might have to scroll horizontally b/c the output for dump is pretty huge.

Comment: I thought the "Killed" problem was gone, but it seems is still there on some devices, or as you may have discovered after some preconditions. Fix will be available soon.

Comment: Please test https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/commit/054433bc3546e8c131bec3dcecf564d5a3a589bc and verify if the problem is solved

Comment: Using dump and/or culebra?

Comment: I was using dump.  The point of failure in the code in any of the scripts is right after making the ViewClient instance.

Comment: I read somewhere that one of the prerequisites to make uiautomator function properly is to disable all accessibility services.  It might not have anything to do with your plugin.

Comment: Anyway, I guess (please confirm) that the latest patch fixes the problem (ignores Killed, because the interesting part is that the dump is received already)

Comment: Still getting the "Killed" message.  Well, it's fine.  The Android CTS requires a factory reset at the beginning anyways, so the accessibility stuff shouldn't be on in the first place.  This is just something that I accidentally stumbled upon while trying to solve other bugs.